# Update plist from background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background, plist

Is it possible to read or write to plist when the application is in background state?

Comment: If somebody have any idea regarding this please respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to read your plist when your application is in the background, because your  application is not running more than 10 minutes in the background state. There are only three options for keeping your application running more than 10 minutes in the background.

If you want to read and write your plist, do this when your application comes to the foreground state. For this you can read and write your plist in the application became active  delegate method.

Comment: Please do not use "u" and "r" for "you" and "are". Textspeak is painful to read.

Answer (score 1):

**try this one..**

```
- (void)readPlist
    {
        NSString *filePath = @"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist";
            NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
            
            NSString *value;
            value = [plistDict objectForKey:@"ProductVersion"];
          
            /* You could now call the string "value" from somewhere to return the value of the string in the .plist specified, for the specified key. */
    }
    - (void)writeToPlist
    {
        NSString *filePath = @"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist";
            NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
            
            [plistDict setValue:@"1.1.1" forKey:@"ProductVersion"];
            [plistDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];

    /* This would change the firmware version in the plist to 1.1.1 by initing the NSDictionary with the plist, then changing the value of the string in the key "ProductVersion" to what you specified */
    }
```

*Hope this helps you!*